# Merge Statement impact on users query

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using the below sort of Merge statement to merge current table and new data table . I was wondering what will happen to a query which the user runs when the Merge statement is being run . Will it show inconsistent results ?

```
MERGE dataset.Inventory T
USING dataset.NewArrivals S
ON T.ProductID = S.ProductID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET quantity = T.quantity + S.quantity
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (ProductID, quantity) VALUES (ProductID, quantity)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BigQuery provides a property known as snapshot isolation, so you will never observe partial results. For a walk-through of how this works, check out [this talk from GCP Next](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KL_i5XZIaJg).

Comment: @Felipe and Elliott, so if my Merge statement takes 5 mins to run and in the meantime if the user runs a query on the same table he/she will see the Merge statement effect instantaneously only after Merge completes successfully in the 5 mins ? Is that how it is ?

Comment: If the user's query starts *before* the MERGE completes, then they *will not* see the effects. If the user's query starts *after* the MERGE completes, they *will* see the effects.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> A MERGE statement is a DML statement that can combine INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE operations into a single statement and perform the operations atomically.

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_statement

Where "*perform the operations atomically*" means users will get consistent results.